# Using Angular to validate radio button choice

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have been given a requirement to display Yes/No radio buttons on a webpage.  In the initial state neither of these options are selected.  There needs to be validation to ensure that the user picks one of these.  I was able to do this using the browsers own form validation, like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-radio-input-directive-production</title>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body ng-app="radioExample">
   <script>
   angular.module('radioExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {      
       $scope.submitForm = function() {
         alert('valid');
   }       
 }]);
 </script>
 <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="ExampleController" novalidate>
   <input name="question" type="radio" ng-model="question" value="yes" required>Yes<br/>
   <input name="question" type="radio" ng-model="question" value="no">No<br/>
   <pre>myForm.question.$error = {{ myForm.question.$error | json }}</pre>
   <div ng-messages="myForm.question.$error" role="alert">
       <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to make use of Angular to display the validation messages in a ng-message but am struggling to make it work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-radio-input-directive-production</title>  
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body ng-app="radioExample">
   <script>
   angular.module('radioExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {       
       $scope.submitForm = function() {
         alert('valid');
       }       
     }]);
 </script>
 <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="ExampleController" novalidate>
   <input name="question" type="radio" ng-model="question" value="yes" required>Yes<br/>
   <input name="question" type="radio" ng-model="question" value="no">No<br/>
   <pre>myForm.question.$error = {{ myForm.question.$error | json }}</pre>
   <div ng-messages="myForm.question.$error" role="alert">
       <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "required" is valid for a radio input. So the browser/Angular behavior is not really specified here. So the problem is, the form is valid. Here a code snippet with what you ask, but it's not really clear and straightful.

```js
angular.module('radioExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {       
  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    alert('valid');
  }       
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="radioExample">
 <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="ExampleController" novalidate>
   <input name="question" type="radio" ng-model="question" value="yes">Yes<br/>
   <input name="question" type="radio" ng-model="question" value="no">No<br/>
   <div ng-if="question!='yes'" role="alert">
       <div>You did not enter a field</div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

HTML:

```
<form ng-app="radioExample"  ng-controller="ExampleController" name="myForm"  novalidate ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <input name="question" type="radio" ng-model="question" value="yes" required>Yes<br/>
    <input name="question" type="radio" ng-model="question" value="no">No<br/>
    <pre>myForm.question.$error = {{ myForm.question.$error | json }}</pre>
    <div ng-messages="myForm.question.$error" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    </div>

    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
 angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.submitForm = function() {
            alert('valid');
            return false;
        }
    }]);
```