# Radio Button Validation not working Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I've been recently started working in AngularJS. I was trying to validate radio button as :-

```html
 <input type="radio" ng-model="CustGender" name="uCustGender" value="Male" required /> Male
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="CustGender" name="uCustGender" value="Female" required /> Female
                            <span class="error" ng-show="(f1.uCustGender.$dirty || submitted) && f1.uCustGender.$error.required">Gender required!</span>

 <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
```

But it's not validating on Button Click. I was searching for solution and came across some links as [Using Angular to validate radio button choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969442/using-angular-to-validate-radio-button-choice) but they seems to have a different approach. 
Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `f1.$submitted` instead of just `submitted` for [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) in your span assuming 'f1' is the form name.

```
<form name="f1" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="CustGender" name="uCustGender" value="Male" required /> Male
  <input type="radio" ng-model="CustGender" name="uCustGender" value="Female" required /> Female
  <span class="error" ng-show="(f1.uCustGender.$dirty || f1.$submitted) && f1.uCustGender.$error.required">Gender required!</span>

  <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks It worked! But Can You explain this? I've another input date parameter which is working correctly with 'submitted' as :-  <span class="error" ng-show="(f1.uCustDoB.$dirty || submitted) && f1.uCustDoB.$error.required">Date of Birth Required!</span> but not the radio button.

Comment: Also this is not working :-  <textarea rows="3" cols="100" type="text" ng-model="CustDescription" maxlength="800" name="uCustDescription" ng-class="submitted?'ng-dirty':''" ></textarea>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="(f1.uCustDescription.$dirty || f1.$submitted) && f1.uCustDescription.$error.required">Description Required!</span>

Comment: f1.$submitted set when ever you submit your form and only 'submitted' will not set or reset unless until explicitly done.

Comment: In case of your Date f1.uCustDoB.$dirty comes in action, thus its working fine.

Comment: In case of your textarea, remove the code for ng-class as it is of no help, rest of the code looks fine <textarea rows="3" cols="100" type="text" ng-model="CustDescription" maxlength="800" name="uCustDescription"></textarea><span class="error" ng-show="(f1.uCustDescription.$dirty || f1.$submitted) && f1.uCustDescription.$error.required">Description Required!</span>

Comment: PLEASE MARK STAR AGAINST ANSWER IF HELPED

Comment: "In case of your Date f1.uCustDoB.$dirty comes in action, thus its working fine. " - same is the case with my input control 'name' only difference is 'name' is type text while 'dob' is tupe date. But still dob validation fires on submit click while name doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have enclosed them in form tag and mentioned novalidate attribute in your form like this:

```
 <form name="f1" ng-submit="submitTeamMember($event)"  novalidate class="form-horizontal"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  ng-controller="userFormModalCtrl">
 <input type="radio" ng-model="CustGender" name="uCustGender" value="Male" required /> Male
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="CustGender" name="uCustGender" value="Female" required /> Female
                            <span class="error" ng-show="(f1.uCustGender.$dirty || submitted) && f1.uCustGender.$error.required">Gender required!</span>

 <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```